# Derived function not returning correct data values

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, radix

Still working on an inheritance program, the base class is a Shape and there are three derived classes: rectangle, Circle, and Square (Square is derived from Rectangle). When I set the data values trough the respective constructors, I get false values for the data members of each derived class when I display them I'm either not setting them correctly (my guess) or I'm not displaying them correctly. Here is a code snippet.

```
class Shape
{
     public:
     Shape(double w = 0, double h = 0, double r = 0)
     {
          width = w;
          height = h;
          radius = r;
     }

     virtual double area() = 0;
     void display();

     protected:
     double width;
     double height;
     double radius;
};
```

One derived class:

```
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
     public:
     Rectangle(double w, double h) : Shape(w, h)
     {
     }

     double area();
     void display();      
};
```

Rectangle's display function:

```
double Rectangle::area()
{
    return width * height;
}
```

Here is my main():

```
#include<iostream>
#include "ShapeClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    Rectangle r(3, 2);
    Circle c(3);
    Square s(3);

    c.display();
    s.display();
    r.display();


    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Complete ShapeClass.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "ShapeClass.h"

using namespace std;

double Shape::area()
{
    return (width * height);
}

double Rectangle::area()
{
    return width * height;
}

double Circle::area()
{
   return (3.14159 * radius * radius);
}

double Square::area()
{
    return width * width;
}

void Square::display()
{
    cout << "Side length of square: " << width << endl;
    cout << "Area of square: " << this->area() << endl;
}

void Circle::display()
{
    cout << "Radius of circle: " << radius << endl;
    cout << "Area of circle: " << this->area() << endl;
}

void Rectangle::display()
{
    cout << "Width of rectangle: " << width << endl;
    cout << "Height of rectangle: " << height << endl;
    cout << "Area of rectangle: " << this->area() << endl;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean **getting false** values?

Comment: You need to be more specific. You haven't posted any malfunctioning code and told us what isn't correct.

Comment: That was a little vague--I'm getting random, very large values--garbage values, essentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your `area()` function virtual in `Rectangle` as well:

```
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
     public:
     Rectangle(double w, double h) : Shape(w, h)
     {
     }

     virtual double area();
     void display();      
};
```

Now, also keep in mind that if you want the `display()` function to be overriden in specific shapes (in your example I see that `Rectangle` also has a `display()` function), then you need to make it virtual as well, in both classes:

```
virtual void display();
```

Edit: I tried the following code and it worked perfectly. It's based on your code, so there might be a problem with how you built your project or how you compile/link it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Shape
{
     public:
     Shape(double w = 0, double h = 0, double r = 0)
     {
          width = w;
          height = h;
          radius = r;
     }

     virtual double area() = 0;
     virtual void display() = 0;

     protected:
     double width;
     double height;
     double radius;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
     public:
     Rectangle(double w, double h) : Shape(w, h)
     {
     }

     virtual double area() { return width * height; }
     virtual void display() 
     {
        cout << "Width of rectangle: " << width << endl;
        cout << "Height of rectangle: " << height << endl;
        cout << "Area of rectangle: " << this->area() << endl;
     }
};



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Rectangle r(3, 2);

    r.display();

    system ("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still returning garbage even after I made both the display functions and area functions virtual, interestingly enough. I create a rectangle: 

Rectangle r(3, 2);

And tell it to display:

r.display();

But it returns very large numbers for my data members (width, height, area)

Comment: I have added it to my original post.

Comment: hmm. might be a problem with your compiler? I'll edit my answer with code that I tried and worked perfectly.

Comment: Make sure you're not mistakenly overriding the construction you defined in the .h file in the c++ file.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by this exactly? I've attached the whole ShapeClass.cpp file with all class definitions.

Comment: Looks fine to me... Try pasting my code into a single file and see if it works. If it does, start moving the fucntions one by one to the c++ file and see when it breaks. This is weird.

Comment: Your code works--looks like mine is identical, but I'm getting linker errors even after creating a fresh project--ahh well! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sure thing. Let us know if you figure out what caused the linker errors.